# Subfigure implementation issues in Latex/Overleaf

Tags: latex

I have this latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./img/matrices/Logestic_Regression.png}
         \caption{Logestic Regression}
         \label{fig: Logrestic Regression}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./img/matrices/Naive_Bayes.png}
         \caption{Naive Bayes}
         \label{fig: Naive Bayes}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./img/matrices/Support_Vector_Machine.png}
         \caption{SVM}
         \label{fig: SVM}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But still showing a error of

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 203--203

And output image alignments are not also as expected.[image]

How to solve this issue? I'm using overleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose one of the packages for subfigures. Don't combine different packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
         \caption{Logestic Regression}
         \label{fig: Logrestic Regression}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
         \caption{Naive Bayes}
         \label{fig: Naive Bayes}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
         \caption{SVM}
         \label{fig: SVM}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three simple graphs}
        \label{fig:three graphs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]